# Send string as json with GET request with POSTMAN

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, api, postman

I have a Java Spring API which expects 2 params, a simple String and a object:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<ListResource> getList(@RequestParam("agentName") String agentName,
                                            @RequestParam("paginationInfo") PaginationInfoList paginationInfo {

       //After http request i expect to have here my java Object PaginationInfoList ready to use

    }
```

I'm, trying to send http GET request with Postman but i get this error, then i suppose that i'm not sending the data object "paginationInfo" in the correct way.

```
"Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.pippo.prova.test.model.in.PaginationInfoList'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.pippo.prova.test.model.in.PaginationInfoList': no matching editors or conversion strategy found"
```

Since i can't change the way of sending, infact must be GET and i have to use @ReuqestParam, i don't know how to send json data in postman parameters. I'm trying this and also other options but i always get error.

[image]

Comment: you can take second argument as a String and pass String to requestParam i postman

And After getting it convert String to Object .

Comment: Ok but in this way i have to map from string to object in Java and i want a READY java object.

Comment: you have to pass it directly without json string.
like `argentName`.
`pageSize` = //
`pageNumber` = //

@MatteoBruni

Comment: Spring will bind it to `PaginationInfoList` class. @MatteoBruni

Answer (score 1):

You can bind The request params to an object. In postman you will have 3 params ("agentName", "pageSize" and "pageNumber") and your controller will receive 2 objects

```
public ResponseEntity<ListResource> getList(@RequestParam("agentName") String agentName,
                                        @Valid PaginationInfoList paginationInfo)
```

http://dolszewski.com/spring/how-to-bind-requestparam-to-object/